# Dirty cells in a range or table

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an Excel add-in using the JavaScript APIs to build add-ins in Excel Office 365. Am trying to do a save operation which will save the changed data in a range or a table to the database. I want to save only the records in the range which are changed and not the entire range. What is the best possible way to achieve this ?
e.g. I have 10 records in a table or range. Only 2 cells of the second row gets changed. Then on click of any save button ( either on ribbon or in the pane ), it should process only the second row for saving to database & not the entire 10.

Comment: How are you managing "save to database" action?

Comment: Sending the changed rows to a rest api to perform save operation

Comment: Ok, I think the answer I gave still holds good. dataChanged event is still the best way to do this. However, there is no event yet (we're working on it) to connect this back to a save action.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Excel JS APIs doesn't support save event notification. So, the only way to detect something changed is by creating dataChanged event binding on the range and get notified on changes. Depending on the number of rows (if it is not large, say more than few hundred rows), you could create individual bindings and know for sure what changed and do database save. This approach doesn't connect DB save action to the workbook save action in anyway.